# Yahoo finance, interactive chart and historical prices are different

Tags: programming, finance, yahoo, split, csv

I am very new to the stocks. I checked the TNTE.AS stock on Yahoo Finance website. Here it provides "Interactive Chart" and "Historical Prices".
But I found they are showing different values.
For example:
in the "Interactive Chart", if you put the cursor for the date (24-March-2015), you can see that the High value of the price is 5.91. But in the "Historical Prices", the High value on date 24-March-2015 is 11.82.

But for the date 25-March-2015, the values from "Interactive Chart" are the same as the values from "Historical Prices".

I know that it may have something to do with "split". But the values from "Interactive Chart" are the ones I want.

So my question is: how do I download an csv.file, which has the values exactly the same as those from "Interactive Chart"? --- Especially for "High" values.

Thank you!

The url for "Interactive Chart" is
http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=TNTE.AS+Interactive#

The url for "Historical Prices" is
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TNTE.AS&d=7&e=25&f=2015&g=d&a=4&b=25&c=2011&z=66&y=66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "adjusted high". However, Yahoo Finance does not provide that: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2311.html

However you can adjust manually. From the Normal Close and the Adjusted Close just compute the adjustment factor and then manually adjust the High.

Comment: your suggestion works well for most dates, but not all of them. Take the TNTE.AS stock for example, on the date of 09-April-2015. The values from "Historical Prices" is 7.66 (Close) and 3.83 (Adj Close). But the values from "Interactive Chart" is 7.66 (Close). So for this date, I should use 7.66, not 3.83. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Without knowing the specific history of that quote, I am afraid I can't be of much help. How did the quotes look like on the previous trading day?

Comment: you may simply check the following two url. They show all the dates, including the 2 dates I mentioned: 24-March-2015, 09-April-2015.

The url for "Interactive Chart" is http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=TNTE.AS+Interactive#

The url for "Historical Prices" is http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TNTE.AS&d=7&e=25&f=2015&g=d&a=4&b=25&c=2011&z=66&y=66